# Do IIS Web Applications that use the same App Pool share DLLs in memory?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I inherited a large web site. To the user, it consists of 20 "modules" with different functionality. Each module can be accessed via a menu from each other module.

Each module has been implemented as a separate Web Application in IIS, all sitting under the Default Web Site. They all use the same App Pool. All implemented in ASP.NET Core (net5).

The modules share about 70% of their code. This library code sits in several projects. The web application projects all have References to the library DLLs. After everything has been built, the bin folder of each web application project has a copy of the library DLLs (so there are then 20 copies of each library DLL on disk).

Assuming that web application 1 is receiving requests and has been loaded into server memory. If web application 2 then gets loaded into server memory, will the library DLLs then be loaded into memory again for web application 2? Or will web application 2 use the library DLLs that have already been loaded into memory for web application 1? As in, after web applications 1 and 2 have been loaded in memory, will there be 1 copy of the library cod in memory or 2 copies?

Reason behind the question is that I need to reduce memory usage on the web server. There are no operational benefits to having separate web applications. They are all deployed together in one go. We never start or stop just one of them, it is always all or nothing. Wondering if I can save memory by having 1 big web application instead of 20 smaller web applications.

Comment: How much memory is being used in the current design? It seems like this aspect would be far less important to consider against other tradeoffs of having a monolith architecture.

Comment: You missed a key setting in your lengthy description. Do you use in-process or out-of-process hosting?  Once you tell that, the answer will be super clear, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#differences-between-in-process-and-out-of-process-hosting

Comment: @LexLi We use out-of-process hosting. This enables us to use one app pool for all the web applications. I read the article you linked to, but it isn't clear to me how the hosting model (in-process or out-of-process) relates to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ASP.NET Core web apps in the same application pool are configured to use [out-of-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0), so all their assemblies/libraries are loaded into **individual .NET Core processes (Kestrel based)** (`dotnet.exe` usually, or your own executable when self contained deployment is used).

> Diagrams in that Microsoft article make it super easy to understand the relationship among the runtime processes.

In that mode, IIS worker process(es) `w3wp.exe` only loads the ASP.NET Core module to work as reverse proxy.

Combining the two above, the answer to your question `Do IIS Web Applications that use the same App Pool share DLLs in memory?` is rather clear that nothing is shared and you cannot share anything either due to the process boundary.